# Using NumLock key to select

Tags: keyboard, mapping, hotkeys

I'm looking to reassign the function of my keyboard's "NumLock" key. Essentially I'd like to use the "NumLock" key to select multiple items on a spreadsheet, instead of using the "Ctrl" key to select multiple items.  Anyone have a quick fix or can direct me to a third party solution?

thanks in advance,

Comment: Other.  For use with a .net grid

Comment: Are you looking for a keyboard macro program (like this: http://www.autohotkey.com/), or do you want to directly change the use of NumLock?

Comment: Thx for response.  With Autohotkey, can I change the function of the NumLock key to have the same native functionality of the Ctrl key?  I want to be able to use an unused key (NumLock or other) on my external usb numerical keypad in order to select multiple grid rows.  Problem is that the Ctrl key is not on the numerical keypad.

Comment: I suppose I could just get a programmable numerical keypad and assign a function to one of the keys for Ctrl?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to achieve this.  One of the neat things about AHK is that it provides [remap functionality](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm), so your numlock key can become a second ctrl.